# How can I change what the Monaco editor considers a word to include special characters?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm building a customized Monaco editor for a proprietary language where the designers thought it was a good idea to include the "|" characters as a legal part of an identifier. When autocompleting an identifier with such a character in it, the autocomplete only includes the part after the "|". I think this is due to the way `model.getWordUntilPosition` works. It seems to want to cut off the word to whatever is after the "|", which indeed would be the normal behavior.

My code looks something like this:

```
`const word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
console.log(word)
const range: monacoType.IRange  = {
   startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
   endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
   startColumn: word.startColumn,
   endColumn: word.endColumn
};`
```

When I type e.g. foo|bar, the `word` variable only contains "bar". How can I modify the behavior of getWordUntilPosition so that it accepts a custom definition of what constitutes a word?